# How to disable all HTML syntax highlighting while editing a Php file in Vim

Tags: php, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I want to  write a Php template which generates some Apache configuration files.

For this matter, while editing the template,
I don't need any HTML syntax highlighting outside the Php tags, because the raw code outside those tags is some Apache configuration, **not** HTML code.

Apache syntax, as well as HTML, uses `<angle brackets>`... Then the standard `php.vim` syntax file causes
some disturbing visual highlightings.

**Question:** Is there a way to disable the highlighting of HTML tags inside a Php file (while keeping the Php syntax), using Vim, and without forking / tweaking the original syntax file?

*Note:* The ideal thing would be to replace HTML syntax by Apache configuration syntax (still outside Php tags), but the most important now is to remove this unwanted HTML syntax highlighting.

Comment: You probably need a custom PHP syntax file that doesn't highlight HTML.

Comment: @staticsan: if so, I will probably give it up... it's not a so crucial point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't that hard to do, but there could be an ongoing maintenance cost if you want to keep the syntax file up to date.

First, find your Vim library. On Mac/Linux systems this is usually someplace like `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/`. There will be a file named `php.vim` there. That's the file containing all of the syntax highlighting rules for PHP.

Make a personal syntax directory, if you don't have one already. Then make a copy of the global php.vim file in that directory.

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.vim/syntax
cp /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/php.vim $HOME/.vim/syntax
```

Then modify the copy you made. The file I found on my system has a section like this near the top.

```
if version < 600
  unlet! php_folding
  if exists("php_sync_method") && !php_sync_method
    let php_sync_method=-1
  endif
  so <sfile>:p:h/html.vim
else
  runtime! syntax/html.vim
  unlet b:current_syntax
endif
```

As you can see, there are two cases where it reads/imports the html.vim file. You can comment those cases out (changes on 3 lines):

```
if version < 600
  unlet! php_folding
  if exists("php_sync_method") && !php_sync_method
    let php_sync_method=-1
  endif
  " so <sfile>:p:h/html.vim
else
  " runtime! syntax/html.vim
  " unlet b:current_syntax
endif
```

The ongoing maintenance cost comes up in this form: as Vim is upgraded, periodically the global php.vim file will be updated. But if you have made your own copy which is being used instead, it does not get those updates (unless you make and patch another copy). Whether that's an issue is up to you.

Comment: In the same time I noticed some kind of bug in the original `php.vim` (version Dec 11, 2016): many Php keywords are highlighted *outside* the php tags! Ex: `PDO`, `Directory`, `Iterator`... But anyway : my problem is solved